# Pod is copying files to PVC which exists @ 564 MB in AKS

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, devops, azure-aks

I have an application, which copies files from pod to PVC once it is deployed, however, it copies upto 564 MB and stops, the full file is 800 MB, is there any limits from Kubernetes or docker for limiting the files

```
#!/bin/bash

# DOCKER ENTRYPOINT FILE FOR MAGENTO 2

# COPYING CONFIGURATION FILES FOR PHP AND NGINX

if [[ ! -z `ls -A /etc/nginx` ]]; then
    echo "[INFO] \"/etc/nginx\" has files in it, not copying."
    rm -rf /tmp/nginx
else
    echo "[INFO] Copying NGINX conf files..."
    cp -r /tmp/nginx/. /etc/nginx/ && rm -rf /tmp/nginx
fi

if [[ ! -z `ls -A /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/` ]]; then
    echo "[INFO] \"/etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm\" has files in it, not copying."
    rm -rf /tmp/fpm
else
    echo "[INFO] Copying PHP conf files..."
    cp -r /tmp/fpm/. /etc/php/${PHP_VERSION}/fpm/ && rm -rf /tmp/fpm
fi

# NGINX VHOST FOR MAGENTO

[[ -z $DOMAIN ]] && DOMAIN="localhost"

vHost() {

    echo "upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  unix:/run/php/php${PHP_VERSION}-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    
    listen 80;
    server_name $DOMAIN;
    set \$MAGE_ROOT $DOC_ROOT;
    include ${NGINX_PREFIX}/magento.conf.d/nginx.conf;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/${DOMAIN}_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/${DOMAIN}_error.log warn;
    
}"
}

[[ ! -L ${NGINX_PREFIX}/sites-enabled/${DOMAIN}.conf ]] && [[ ! -f ${NGINX_PREFIX}/sites-enabled/${DOMAIN}.conf ]] &&
{
    echo; echo "[INFO] Creating vHost for the domain \"$DOMAIN\"..."
    mkdir ${NGINX_PREFIX}/magento.conf.d/ && cp -f /tmp/nginx.conf.sample ${NGINX_PREFIX}/magento.conf.d/nginx.conf && rm -f /tmp/nginx.conf.sample
    vHost > ${VHOST_DIR}/${DOMAIN}.conf

    ln -s ${VHOST_DIR}/${DOMAIN}.conf ${NGINX_PREFIX}/sites-enabled
    [[ -L "${NGINX_PREFIX}/sites-enabled/default" ]] && unlink ${NGINX_PREFIX}/sites-enabled/default
}

# COPYING MAGENTO FILES TO DOCUMENT ROOT:

if [[ -f "${DOC_ROOT}/bin/magento" ]] && [[ -d "${DOC_ROOT}/app" ]] && [[ -d "${DOC_ROOT}/vendor" ]] && [[ -d "${DOC_ROOT}/pub" ]]; then
    echo "[INFO] Looks like Magento files are already present on the document root."
    rm -rf /tmp/magento/
    chmod 755 ${DOC_ROOT}/bin/magento
    chown ${NGINX_USER}:${NGINX_USER} -R ${DOC_ROOT}/var ${DOC_ROOT}/pub ${DOC_ROOT}/generated;
else
    echo "[INFO] Copying Magento files to the document root..."
    mv /tmp/magento.zip /var/www/html/ && cd /var/www/html && unzip magento.zip && rm -rf magento.zip
    chmod 755 ${DOC_ROOT}
    chown ${NGINX_USER}:${NGINX_USER} -R ${DOC_ROOT};
fi

exec "$@"
```

PVC files

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:

  name: magento-pvc-42
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: Show us your pvc.yaml where storage is defined.

Comment: I have added PVC, please check

Comment: There could be a network drop or application code issue causing this to happen. There are no such limits from Kubernetes or docker